# How to fit a curve in a picture with an equation?

Tags: image-processing, fitting

For a curve taken from a picture, is there any method to fit it with an equation if it appears to be some standard curve?

For example, in the following picture, the curve looks like an ellipse or a circle or something else of a conic section. How can I fit the shape with a proper equation using Mathematica? Furthermore, is it possible to assess two different fittings with a criterion (e.g. error)? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

A simple approach is as follows.  Define the input curve

[image: Input curve]

Extract the (x,y) points

```
xy = SortBy[
   Reverse /@ 
    First /@ Drop[ArrayRules[1 - ImageData[Binarize[curve]]], -1], 
   First];
```

Find a formula - you will probably want to do a little better than this - `FindFormula` offers many options

```
fitxy = FindFormula[xy];
```

and compare the results

```
Show[{ListLinePlot[xy], 
  Plot[fitxy[x], {x, Min[First /@ xy], Max[First /@ xy]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image: fitted curve]

Comment: `xy` might be extracted more easily with `xy = PixelValuePositions[curve, 0 ]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann that doesn't work for me - but I may have a different definition of `curve`. I need to apply `Binarize` to `curve`.   And perhaps fiddle some more.

Comment: I just copied the image into the Mathematica code `curve= "copy of image" `. No need to binarize because black&white image.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I guess we copied the image in different ways.

Comment: my way: right click -> copy picure ->paste in Mathematica

Answer (score 6):

### Get (x, y) points from the image pixel positions

```
curve = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG8W9.png"];
```

Get points from the image. For RGB images, use `PixelValuePositions` and *Black* to locate pixel positions, or use *0* with single-channel images.

```
(*for RGB images*)    
xy = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
  NumericalSort[PixelValuePositions[curve, Black, .5]], First];

(*for single-channel images*)
curve2 = ColorSeparate[curve, "I"];(*make a 1-channel image*)
xy = DeleteDuplicatesBy[
  NumericalSort[PixelValuePositions[curve2, 0, .5]], First];
```

### Demonstrate various methods to fit a model to the (x, y) data

**1. Use FindFormula to make a piece-wise fit**

```
fit = FindFormula[xy, x, TargetFunctions->{Times, Plus, Power}];
Show[{ListLinePlot[xy],
  Plot[fit, {x, Min[First/@xy], Max[First/@xy]},
   PlotStyle->Red]}]
```

[image: piece-wise plot]

**2. Assuming a circle fits the (x, y) data, use three points to find the center and radius**

```
pts = xy[[{1, Round@Length[xy]/2, -1}]]
(*{{34, 78}, {156, 175}, {279, 78}}*)
circle = CircleThrough[pts];
center = RegionCentroid[circle];
radius = Last@circle;
Graphics[{circle,
  Point[xy],
  PointSize[Scaled[.02]], Blue, Point[center], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image: circle plot]

**3. Use Bspline and Bezier modeling**

Find a function definition with `BSplineFunction`:

```
f = BSplineFunction[xy];
Show[{Graphics[{Point[xy], PointSize[Scaled[.02]]}],
  ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle->Red]}]
```

[image: BSline plot]

Or use `BezierCurve` to plot a spline curve:

```
Graphics[{Point[xy], Red, BezierCurve[xy]}]
```

[image: BezierCurve plot]

**4. Fitting using Fit, FindFit, etc.**

Demonstrate `Fit` using quadratic and quartic models

```
quad = Fit[xy, {1, x, x^2}, x]
(*25.3532 + 1.72048x - 0.00950413 x^2*)
quart = Fit[xy, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]
(*-17.13974517615123 + 4.458526401451207 x - 0.0657189150882205 x^2 + 0.00045398967260661826 x^3 - 1.2540520088334156*^-6 x^4*)
{x1, xn} = First/@xy[[{1, -1}]];
Show[ListPlot[xy, PlotStyle->Black],
  Plot[{quad, quart}, {x, x1, xn}, PlotStyle->{{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}]]
```

[image: Fit plot]

**5. LinearModelFit provides information that compares the fitted models**

```
lm1 = LinearModelFit[xy, {1, x, x^2}, x];
lm1[{"BestFit", "RSquared", "ANOVATable"}] // Column
```

[image: quadratic model fit]

```
lm2 = LinearModelFit[xy, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x];
lm2[{"BestFit", "RSquared", "ANOVATable"}] // Column
```

[image: quartic model fit]

```
{x1, xn} = First/@xy[[{1, -1}]];
Show[ListPlot[xy, PlotStyle->Black],
Plot[{lm1[x], lm2[x]}, {x, x1, xn}, PlotStyle->{{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}]]
```

[image: LinearModelFit plot]

Comment: Given such a comprehensive answer, it seems pedantic to note that least squares fitting considers only the error in y, which is not quite the right thing to do (with some assumptions, anyway)